# Grails - IntelliJ can't resolve symbols and objects

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails

ItelliJ can't resolve grails symbols. For example symbol 'group' in UrlMapping.groovy.

It's happening in every project with grails 3 or greater (in grails 2.4.4 everything works fine).

I did try to import project, open project, create new project in IntelliJ, create project in 'grails' interactive mode etc.

My suspicion is that either I'm doing something wrong with opening/creating Gradle project or maybe there is something wrong with my settings in IntelliJ.

This is example of that behaviour:

[image: example]

I'm using following versions:

- IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: intellij]

- Grails installed with sdkman - version 4.0.3
- Java installed with sdkman - version 8.0.242.hs-adpt

How can I set IntelliJ to work just fine with grails?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach a small sample project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks - link to issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238578